# Xcode 6.1 The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content

Tags: ios, xcode

When I goto Archive my app and check in Window -> Organizer -> Archives my app has no image:

[image]

I goto my Apps General Tab and see Launch Images Source is set to LaunchImage like so:

[image]

I goto check it out and see there are no images:

[image]

I populated the blank images by dragging the images from finder into the spots. I goto build my app and it fails with this error:

The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content. My Icon is png format and is 57 x 57 (for all of them)

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

57x57 image is for 1x, for 2x you should provide 114x114 image, also name of images are like Icon.png for 1x and Icon@2x.png for 2x